# FirestoreRecycleview not load data after Switch menu in Bottom Navbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I made FirestoreRecycleview in home-menu, when run app `FirestoreRecycler` work properly but when I open other Menu in Bottom Navbar, `FirestoreReclyclerview` not Load data

for Example :

- I Have Bottom Navbar with 2 Fragment A and B
- In Fragment A, I Have A RecycleView with Adapter From FirestoreRecyclerAdapter
- when I open Fragment B and open Fragment A again, fragment A doesn't show Data in recyclerview

This is When run app in First Time :

[image: This is when I run app in First time]

This is After I Click other navbar button and open this fragment again :

[image: This is after I Choose other Navbar menu]

this is my code that I call in `onCreate()`

```
 private void setkelaslist() {
        Query query = fdb.collection("kelas").whereEqualTo("email",email_txt);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<kelas_profil> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<kelas_profil>().
                setQuery(query,kelas_profil.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new listkelasadapter(options,this);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        adapter.startListening();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Another request: one more question, I delete items with a button click, it is deleted but when I create a new item with same data, in Toast it says Complete but it doesn't add data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot adding start listening method for your adapters.

    `@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }`

Comment: I have add onstart.. But it still show the same problem... Sometime show and not.. Maybe network or something either?